# What should I be testing in my rails application's model when using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

Hopefully this is a simple question...

I see that devise looks to be well tested, but I'd rather be safe than sorry. What are the minimum items one needs to test in a model spec that aren't already covered by devise's own tests?

Using ruby 2.1.2, rails 4.1.6, rspec-rails 3.1.0, & devise 3.3.0. Currently my model spec looks like:

```rb
describe User do
  before(:each) { @user = create(:user) }

  subject { @user }

  describe "factory" do
    it { should be_valid }
  end

  describe "class instance" do
    it { should respond_to(:email) }
    it { should respond_to(:encrypted_password) }
    it { should respond_to(:reset_password_token) }
    it { should respond_to(:reset_password_sent_at) }
    it { should respond_to(:remember_created_at) }
    it { should respond_to(:sign_in_count) }
    it { should respond_to(:current_sign_in_at) }
    it { should respond_to(:last_sign_in_at) }
    it { should respond_to(:current_sign_in_ip) }
    it { should respond_to(:last_sign_in_ip) }
    it { should respond_to(:created_at) }
    it { should respond_to(:updated_at) }
    it { should respond_to(:name) }
  end

  describe "name" do
    context "when it's not present" do
      before { @user.name = " " }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    context "when it's too long" do
      before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    context "when it's long enough" do
      before { @user.name = "a" * 50 }
      it { should be_valid }
    end
  end

  describe "email" do
    context "when it's not present" do
      before { @user.email = " " }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    context "when it's format is invalid" do
      it "should not be valid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar..com]
        addresses.each do |invalid_address|
          @user.email = invalid_address
          expect(@user).not_to be_valid
        end
      end
    end

    context "when it's format is valid" do
      it "should be valid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
        addresses.each do |valid_address|
          @user.email = valid_address
          expect(@user).to be_valid
        end
      end
    end

    context "when it's already taken" do
      let(:new_user) { create(:user) }

      before { @user = build(:user, email: new_user.email) }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    context "address with mixed case" do
      let(:mixed_case_email) { "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM" }

      it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
        @user.email = mixed_case_email
        @user.save
        expect(@user.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
      end
    end
  end

  describe "password" do
    context "when it's not present" do
      before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    context "when it doesn't match the password confirmation" do
      before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    context "when it's too short" do
      before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * (Rails.application.config.devise.password_length.min - 1) }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end
end
```

Things like including factory_girl methods, the actual factory configuration, including rails/spec_helper, and other setup/config options are omitted...let me know if I should include these or any other items to help clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to testing features implemented through third-party code would probably consist of three lines of defense:

1. Test model validity before any operations are performed.  You've done that in your `describe "factory"` spec.
2. Test that model validations work as expected.  This often feels like overkill, but it's valuable for regression testing, and I have occasionally caught errors from validations that were overly broad or narrow.  Anyway, you've also done this.
3. Write acceptance tests showing that key application-level interactions like login, logout, reset password, etc. are working as expected.  For this, you'll need to use Capybara or something similar.

Comment: I'm guessing that the acceptance tests should be done in a feature spec, no?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It can be a standard Rails integration test or use Capybara or some other equivalent.  Anything that exercises the whole application in the same way as the end user from the browser.